# How to change color of the password toggle in TextInputLayout?

Tags: android, material-design, android-textinputlayout, material-components-android, material-components

I need to change color of the password toggle in `TextInputLayout` if `EditText` is focused or not. I've done it this way but it's not working. The color is always equals color light grey (from state focused = false)

layout

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
        app:passwordToggleDrawable="@drawable/password_toggle_selector"
        app:passwordToggleTint="@color/color_password_toggle">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

color_password_toggle

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/color_green" android:state_checked="true"  />
    <item android:color="@color/color_grey" android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/color_light_grey" android:state_focused="false" />
```

password_toggle_selector

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_eye" android:state_checked="true />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_eye_off" />
```

Answer (score 12):

With the [`TextInputLayout`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/TextInputLayout.md) included in [Material Components library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android)
the `passwordToggleTint` attribute (the icon to use for the password input visibility toggle) is **deprecated**.

Now just use the **`endIconTint`** attribute.

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    ...
    app:endIconMode="password_toggle"
    android:hint="Password"
    style="@style/FilledBoxEndIconTint">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
         ...
         android:inputType="textPassword"/>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

with:

```
  <style name="FilledBoxEndIconTint" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
    <item name="endIconTint">@color/my_selector_color</item>
  </style>
```

You can use a color or a selector.

[image]

You can also use the `app:endIconTint` attribute in the layout:

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            ...
            app:endIconMode="password_toggle"
            android:hint="Password"
            app:endIconTint="@color/my_selector_color">
```

The default selector is:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:color="?attr/colorPrimary" android:state_activated="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.38" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface" android:state_enabled="false"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.6" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: it's not helped me. 
it works [like that](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ZkrNmvFpe7N1KxBDmUeIr3NKx4XMnWO9)

but i [need so](https://drive.google.com/open?id=11MBzuM4cJ8qOrwCIFq7jRBHMNx7Vjbt-)

Comment: It is the standard component with a standard behavior.Just change the color in the selector but you can't introduce new states.

Answer (score 11):

I used : app:passwordToggleTint="@android:color/black" inside TextInputLayout

Comment: simple and best answer

Answer (score 7):

Create color_password_toggle.xml in res/color directory :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:color="@color/color_green" android:state_checked="true"  />
<item android:color="@color/color_light_grey" android:state_checked="false" />
```

And you can remove the custom icon to use the default eye icon :

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
        app:passwordToggleTint="@color/color_password_toggle">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: I added color_password_toggle to res/color directory and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when `TextInputEditText` gains focus, it does not set `TextInputLayout` state to `state_activated`.

However, it is easy to achieve that if you create your own version of `TextInputEditText`.

```java
class MyTextInputEditText : TextInputEditText {
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs)
    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)

    override fun onFocusChanged(focused: Boolean, direction: Int, previouslyFocusedRect: Rect?) {
        super.onFocusChanged(focused, direction, previouslyFocusedRect)
        getTextInputLayout()?.setEndIconActivated(focused)
    }

    //copied from TextInputEditText (why this is private?)
    private fun getTextInputLayout(): TextInputLayout? {
        var parent = parent
        while (parent is View) {
            if (parent is TextInputLayout) {
                return parent
            }
            parent = parent.getParent()
        }
        return null
    }
}
```

And basically just do what [@gabriele-mariotti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2016562/gabriele-mariotti) recommended, create a selector combining `android:state_activated`, `android:state_enabled` and `android:state_checked` for your needs.

I've suggested a change in the Material library, [check the PR](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/pull/1238) on GitHub.